# How to send image to images.google.com and get answer: "search by image"

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-image-search

I need to create android application using Phonegap. Phonegap takes a picture, saves it (using default camera app) and I would like to send that image to images.google.com in order to get "search by image" answer (it can be in default browser that is installed on android - phonegap can close itself and open browser).

Now, if you drag and drop in browser, you will get this automatically, but does anyone know how to get same result from javascript?

I gave up using any kind of api for it and tried to use POST. This is the html code:

```
<form action="http://images.google.com/searchbyimage/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="image_url" id="image_url" />
<input type="hidden" name="btnG" id="btnG" value="Search" />
<input type="file" name="encoded_image" id="encoded_image" value="C:\xampp\htdocs\test\bundy.bmp" />
<input type="hidden" name="image_content" id="image_content" />
<input type="hidden" name="filename" id="filename" />
<input type="hidden" name="hl" id="hl" value="en" />
<input type="hidden" name="bih" id="bih" value="507" />
<input type="hidden" name="biw" id="biw" value="biw" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Now: it works just great if user chooses a picture himself and click upload, but for security reasons, only user can do it. My initial idea was to set via js a default value in the form (input type="file"...), and auto-submit it, but I cant touch this from js/html side.

Does anyone has idea how to go around this problem?

EDIT: I have this idea instead of "file" I use type="text" and into its value I put image read using fopen (or sth like that - I try php on localhost now as it is easier for testing).  So far no success. Any clues?

EDIT2: and another idea is to go directly to https://www.google.com/search with image send in base64, but I don't have google fingerprint (one of reasons they generate is is propably becouse they dont want to be "hacked" like that :D )

Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? (I'm trying to find a way to submit base64 encoded images from an HTML5 canvas).

Comment: Sorry but indeed I did not. My aplication idea was abandomed eventually. It seems google doesn't like to use they services this way.

Answer (score -4):

use alt tag for ex alt = "image title"
this will help the indexing of image on google

Comment: Sorry, but how is SEO any usefull here :)

Comment: SEO is very usefull here because whenever google is indexing your website , the images are get through the alt tag provided in the image tag which give the description about the image.   If you any enquiry feel free to ask me or post comment....

Comment: Thanx for reply, and yes, but it's not even website but a phonepag app. Maybe I dont get what you try to say to me but basicly there will be nothing to index for google. I dont save any image anywhere or give any link (it's an idea too - put image on serwer and give link to google). What is want is: simulate what you can achieve by dragg&dropp single image from hard drive to http://images.google.com/imghp?sbi=1 (so basicly its reverse image search). The most "do-able" idea is not to somehow put base64 string with encoded image to google search (but I don't have fingerprint). Any ideas guys?

Comment: I must say for this you have to promote your app through blogs , ads, rss feeds, content , description and links. The App which is popular automatically is indexed by the Google and its relevant images are shown on Google